# How to switch from one Drawer screen to a non-Drawer Screen in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to know one easy way to switch from one screen to another. Because I am really getting frustrated with this issue. I have declared one stack navigator in my HomeScreen to initialize the starting the screen. Here is the code for that-

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen';
import NoteMeHome from './components/NoteMeHome';
import HomeDrawer from './HomeDrawer/HomeDrawer';
import SettingsScreen from './components/SettingsScreen';
import TestScreen from './components/TestScreen';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    getValue: null,

  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('toke');
    this.setState({ getValue: token });

  }

  render() {
    console.log('#ZZZ:', this.state.getValue);

    if(this.state.getValue !== null) {
      return (
        <AppStackNavigator/>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppStackNavigator2/>
      );
    }

  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},

  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},

  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen},
  TestScreen: {screen:TestScreen}

})

const AppStackNavigator2 = new StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer
  },

  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},

  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen},
  TestScreen: {screen:TestScreen}

})

export default HomeScreen;
```

After Login, for the next screen I have created one class with Drawer navigation named HomeDrawer. Here's the code for that-

**HomeDrawer.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image, AsyncStorage, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Icon, Header, Body} from 'native-base';
import {DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator, DrawerItems, SafeAreaView} from 'react-navigation';

import NoteMeHome from '../components/NoteMeHome';
import SettingsScreen from '../components/SettingsScreen';

import {Root} from 'native-base';
import {Font, AppLoading} from 'expo';
import WelcomeScreen from "../WelcomeScreen";

let user_email ='', user_first_name='';

class HomeDrawer extends Component {

  state = {

    loading: true
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null
}

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user_email").then(value => {
      console.log(value);
      // you will need to handle case when `@ProductTour:key` is not exists
     user_email = value;
    });

    AsyncStorage.getItem("user_first_name").then(value => {
      console.log(value);
      // you will need to handle case when `@ProductTour:key` is not exists
     user_first_name = value;
    });

  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync ({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
    });
    this.setState({loading:false});
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.loading) {
      return(
        <Root>
          <AppLoading/>
        </Root>
      )
    }
    return(
      <MyApp/>
    )

  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

 <View style={{backgroundColor:"#ffff", height:'100%'}}>

      <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/header.jpeg')} style={{width: '100%', height: 150,  resizeMode:'cover', backgroundColor:"@aaaa"}}>  
      <Body style={styles.drawerBody}>
        <Image
          style={styles.drawerImage}
          source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/administrator-male.png'}}
        />
        <View style={styles.drawerHeaderText}>
          <Text style={{color:'#ffffff', fontSize:20, fontWeight:'400'}}>{user_email}</Text>
          <Text style={{color:'#ffffff', fontSize:16, fontWeight:'200'}}>{user_first_name}</Text>
        </View>

      </Body>


      </ImageBackground>


    <Content style={{marginTop:30 }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </Content>

  </View>



);

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  NoteMeHome:{
    screen: NoteMeHome
  },
  Settings:{
    screen: SettingsScreen
  },
  WelcomeScreen : {
    screen: WelcomeScreen
  }


},

{
  initialRouteName: 'NoteMeHome',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}


);

export default HomeDrawer;
```

I have created the SettingsScreen.js for the Drawer navigator. Here's the code for that-

**SettingsScreen.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Icon, Button} from 'native-base';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Settings",
    headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{paddingLeft:10}}
    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>,

    drawerIcon: 

    <Image source={{uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/automatic.png'}}
            style={styles.icon}
    />
  })

  render() {


    return(


      <Container>
        <CustomHeader
          title="Settings"
          drawerOpen={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', 
        justifyContent:'center', padding:10}}>
        <Button full onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('TestScreen')}>
          <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Go To Test Screen</Text>
        </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }

}

export default SettingsScreen;
```

Now, the problem is- 
You can see in my SettingsScreen.js file, I have added this line on button press-

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('TestScreen')
```

Which should Start the TestScreen class which is outside the drawer navigation. Here's the code for that-

**TestScreen.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';

class TestScreen extends Component {
render() {

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Hello from Test Screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }

}

export default TestScreen;
```

But, after clicking the button in SettingsScreen.js class nothing is working. I can visit the other class inside the HomeDrawer, by changing the code onPress. But in case of any other class which is outside the drawer navigation then it is not working.

The version I used for react-navigation is-

> react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.23

I don't want to update this version because in the latest version, my code was showing some other errors. So, please answer the question if the anyone can help me with the current configuration of the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** 
please update react-navigation by using `npm -i react-navigation@latest`

and also you need to refer the below link before using the code. there is so much things we need to take care after update.

link:   https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html

**Original Answer**

You can use switch navigator for your purpose.

first you have to make a navigation class,

eg:

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

...
...
...

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},
  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen},
  TestScreen: {screen:TestScreen}
})

const AppStackNavigator2 = createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen:LoginScreen},
  WelcomeScreen: {screen:WelcomeScreen},
  HomeDrawer: {screen:HomeDrawer},
  NoteMeHome: {screen:NoteMeHome},
  SettingsScreen: {screen:SettingsScreen},
  TestScreen: {screen:TestScreen}
})

const DrawerNavi = createDrawerNavigator({
  NoteMeHome:{ screen: NoteMeHome},
  Settings:{ screen: SettingsScreen},
  WelcomeScreen : { screen: WelcomeScreen}
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'NoteMeHome',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
);

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AppStackNavigator: AppStackNavigator,
    AppStackNavigator2: AppStackNavigator2,
    DrawerNavi: DrawerNavi
  },
  { headerMode: "none", initialRouteName: "AppStackNavigator" }
);

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default App;
```

Then you can switch those navigations by using,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("AppStackNavigator2");
```

Comment: Well, I did the things you mentioned. At first I created a SwitchNavigation class and pasted all your code in that class. After this I importes the App in my SettingsScreen.js file. After running the project it is showing the following error-

undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _reactNavigation.createStackNavigator)...')

Comment: Did you import all files from "react-navigation" at top?

Comment: Did you import your classes in file, ie. 'LoginScreen', 'WelcomeScreen', ..etc?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here you can check that-
[link] https://codeshare.io/5ogMgg

Comment: First you have to update your react-navigation to version 3.6.1. The features I used to implement the logic needed latest version. Please try and let me know.

Comment: just updated the answer, hope it helps , keep coding